# Get actual size of applied texture to physicsBody?

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody, sknode

My textures are masked and contain my character model in various frames. This is to have constant animations since the size of the character may vary a little in size (for example the character could stretch out an arm, which would increase its size horizontally). Generally: is this a valid approach or how do you handle this?

`SKPhysicsBody(texture: character.texture(), size: CGSizeMake(100, 100))` applies the unmasked character model, which is smaller than 100x100, perfectly to my node.

However, how do I now obtain the actual applied size of the applied `physicsBody`?